# Failed installation of 14.04.01 LTS on upgrade from 12.04.01 LTS running on partition of Acer laptop with Windows Vista on separate partition

Tags: upgrade, lts, windows-vista

I've successfully run Ubuntu 12.04.01 on a partition on an older Acer laptop with Vista as the original OS, which still was accessible, until I, against my better judgment, acceded to the continual prompts to upgrade to 14.04.01 LTS, and did so last week.  Took hours, as warned, but proceeded without any problems until the final prompt to restart computer.  What appeared, after selecting Ubuntu on the OS page, was a black screen with lavender borders followed by a black screen with the following in command line font ( I'll abbreviate for brevity):

```
FOUR LINES OF  mount: mounting
FOLLOWED BY /dev/loop0 on /root failed: Invalid argument
THEN  /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
THEN /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
THEN  /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
THEN NEW LINE  Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
NEW LINE  No init found.  Try passing init+ bootarg.
NEW LINE  BusyBox v.1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
THEN  Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
THEN  (initramfs)
AND CURSOR.
```

Nothing I've tried has succeeded, and not only am I unable to get 14.04.01 LTS to work, but I am also unable to get Vista to boot, or even go into any repair mode.  Wouldn't bother with this, except I have vital data in the old LTS that I didn't back up externally. Sorry for the length of question - I'm no novice, but at wit's end.  I don't expect my patients to define the parameters of the surgeries I perform, but I take extensive histories, in addition to performing extensive physicals, before I do anything, as is true in analogy for my biotech clients,  so for the true Ubuntu experts & developers, please forgive the exactness of my question.

Comment: Please remove the extra customization in that question. It is too difficult to move the whole scroll bar and read.

Comment: Two things.  (1) Don't use an indent at the beginning of your text, it applies code formatting, and doesn't help you.  You don't need perfect english grammar writing skills here, so skip the initial indent.  (2) Your post is pretty much a wall of text at this point, can you maybe split up your thoughts into independent paragraphs/sections?

Answer (score 0):

```
This issue will occur in dual OS setup. Please follow the below steps check
```

- select Ubuntu from the boot manager,
- hold the shift key This brings up Grub manager
- With the first line selected, hit "e" (for edit)
- Hunt down through the boot instructions to a long command line that includes options "ro quiet splash"
- Change the "ro" to "rw" (readonly to read-write)
- ctl-x to save and run

Hope this helps